# Get parsed groovy script methods

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have this groovy script:

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = shell.parse("def myStuff(a){ return a }");
```

How can I get from `script` the list of all declared functions?

I already tried `script.getMetaClass().getMetaMethods()` but `myStuff` function isn't listed.

Comment: Found it! `script.getMetaClass().getMethods()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to invoke your method:

#### 1. You can search for it in `script.getMetaClass().getMethods()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    Script script = shell.parse("def myStuff(a){ return a }");

    script.getMetaClass()
            .getMethods()
            .stream()
            .filter(it -> it.getName().equals("myStuff"))
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(method -> {
                final Object result = method.doMethodInvoke(script, new Object[]{3});
                System.out.println("result = " + result);
            });
}
```

Output:

```
result = 3
```

#### 2. You can use `script.invokeMethod(String name, Object args)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    Script script = shell.parse("def myStuff(a){ return a }");

    System.out.println(script.invokeMethod("myStuff", 5));
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Is possible to find out on `script.getMetaClass().getMethods()` if a method is declared in script? In the case above I can filter methods `method.getDeclaringClass().getTheClass() == script.getClass()` but even so I got 3 methods: `myStuff`, `run` and `main` (injected by groovy compiler I think so).

Comment: @BetoNeto `run` and `main` method comes from parent class - each Groovy script creates a class (it uses script name as a class name) that extends `groovy.lang.Script` class. In `main` method your script class gets initialized and `run` methods runs the body of the script. So if you exclude `run` and `main` methods you should get a list of methods declared in the script file.

Answer (score 1):

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = shell.parse("def myStuff(a){ return a }");

println script.getClass().getDeclaredMethods().find{it.name=='myStuff'}
```

output:

```
public java.lang.Object Script1.myStuff(java.lang.Object)
```